Is the community here tolerant of polling questions?
I came across this question yesterday: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25658/should-i-buy-place-on-altcoindesk-tk
I figured that it would be closed because it is a simple polling question about a specific site and their services. I know that SE discourages polling questions across the board and I tend to agree with their assessment.
I would vote to close that question myself as opinion based because it is, but what does the community at large want to do?

According to our community guidelines those questions are off-topic. I feel that it clearly falls into the "subjective" category. I routinely close such questions as off-topic under the "service recommendation" reason.
On a related note, perhaps we should update that explanation to include "service reviews".

"perhaps we should update that explanation to include 'service reviews.'" Yes, probably. Service reviews are fully opinion based. Using and having a specific close reason is even better; it shows that it has already been thought about and is not really open for discussion.
